# How to integrate coupled differential equations?

Tags: python, integration

I've got a system of equations that I've been tryin to get Python to solve and plot but the plot is not coming out right.
This is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#function that returns dx/dt and dy/dt
def func(z,t):
    for r in range(-10,10):
                beta=2
                gamma=0.8

                c = z[0]
                tau = z[1]
                dcdt = r*c+c**2-c**3-beta*c*tau**2
                dtaudt = -gamma*tau+0.5*beta*c*tau
    return [dcdt,dtaudt]

#inital conditions
z0 = [2,0]

#time points
t = np.linspace(0,24,100)

#solve ODE
z = odeint(func,z0,t)

#seperating answers out

c = z[:,0]
tau = z[:,1]

print(z)


#plot results
plt.plot(t,c,'r-')
plt.plot(t,tau,'b--')
plt.legend(['c(t)','tau(t)'])
plt.show()
```

Let me explain. I am studying doubly diffusive convection. I din't want any assumptions to be made on the value of r, but beta and gamma are positive. So I thougt to assign values to them but not to r.
This is the plot I get and from understanding the problem, that the graph is not right. The tau plot should efinitely not be stuck on 0 and the c plot should be doing more. I am relitively new to Python and am taking courses but really want to understand what I've done wrong, so help in a simple language would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems in your function that you should check.

```
    for r in range(-10,10):
```

Here you are doing a for loop just reevaluating dcdt and dtaudt. As a result, the output value is the same as just evaluating r=9 (last value in the loop)

```
    dtaudt = -gamma*tau+0.5*beta*c*tau
```

Here you have `dtaudt = tau*(beta*c/2. -gamma)`. Your choice `tau[0]=0` implies that tau will remain 0.

Try this:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 1
beta=2
gamma=0.8

#function that returns dx/dt and dy/dt
def func(z,t):
    c = z[0]
    tau = z[1]
    dcdt = r*c+c**2-c**3-beta*c*tau**2
    dtaudt = -gamma*tau+0.5*beta*c*tau
    print(dtaudt)
    return [dcdt,dtaudt]

#inital conditions
z0 = [2,0.2] #tau[0] =!0.0

#time points
t = np.linspace(0,24,100)

#solve ODE
z = odeint(func,z0,t)

#seperating answers out

c = z[:,0]
tau = z[:,1]

#plot results
plt.plot(t,c,'r-')
plt.plot(t,tau,'b--')
plt.legend(['c(t)','tau(t)'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have tried your code and it seems to be working better. A quick question: How can I adjust it to plot it for different values of r?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Maybe the easiest way is to generate a loop like the one you previously have but just before the #solve ODE line.